# Chained strsep gives segmentation fault - C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strtok, strsep

I'm trying to create an array of array of strings to prepare them to be shown in a table.

So I have a function that returns a buffer string with the list of some scanned wifi access points, and I'm using `strsep` to split it by `"\n"` and then again by `"\t"`.

The loop runs fine until it reaches the end and when the `while` argument `((line = strsep(&buf, "\n")))` is evaluated it gives a `SEGFAULT`.

Short Illustrative example asked per @Jabberwocky:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int
wap_scan_count_lines(char*      wap_scan)
{
    int   line_amount = 0;
    char *scan = wap_scan;

    while(*scan)
    {
        if ('\n' == *scan){
            line_amount++;
        }
        scan++;
    }
    return line_amount;
}

int main() {

    char ***scan_result, *line=NULL, *item=NULL, *scan=NULL;
    scan = strdup("bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid\n"
                  "a8:6a:bb:e2:d6:ef       5785    -47     [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS]       Fibertel WiFi114 5.8GHz");
    int wap_scan_size = wap_scan_count_lines(scan);
    scan_result = malloc(wap_scan_size * sizeof(**scan_result));
    int i = 0;
    int item_len = sizeof (*scan_result);

    while((line = strsep(&scan, "\n")) != NULL ) {
        if(i==0){
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        char **scan_line = calloc(5, item_len);
        int j = 0;
        while ((item = strsep(&line, "\t")) != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", item);
            scan_line[j++] = strdup(item);
        }
        scan_result[i++] = scan_line;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The real function that gives me the problem:

```
char *** wifi_client_get_wap_list(int *len)
{
    char ***scan_result;
    char *buf, *buf_free, *cmd, *line, *item;
    int ret, items_len;
    cmd = strdup("SCAN");
    ret = wpa_ctrl_command(cmd, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) goto error;

    cmd = strdup("SCAN_RESULTS");
    ret = wpa_ctrl_command(cmd, &buf); //RETURNS A STRING ON BUF ALLOCATED BY STRDUP
    if (ret < 0){
        free(buf);
        goto error;
    }

    *len = wap_scan_count_lines(buf); //NUMBER OF LINES IN THE SCAN RESULT
    scan_result = calloc(*len, sizeof(**scan_result));
    int i = 0, j;
    buf_free = buf;
    items_len = sizeof (*scan_result);

    while ((line = strsep(&buf, "\n"))){ //THIS GIVES THE SEGFAULT AT THE END
        // SKIP FIRST LINE WITH HEADERS
        if (i==0){
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        //if (strcmp(line, "") == 0) {
        //  break;   
        //}

       //EACH LINE HAS 5 VALUES (bssid, freq, level,flags,ssid)
        char **scan_line = calloc(5, items_len); 
        j = 0;
        printf("INNER STEPS:\n");
        while((item = strsep(&line, "\t"))){
            *(scan_line + j) = strdup(item);
            printf("%d ", j);
            j++;
        }
        *(scan_result + i) = scan_line;
        printf("\nSTEP: %d\n", i);
        i++;
    }

    free(buf_free);
    free(cmd);
    return scan_result;

    error:
    // @TODO: Handle error
    if (ret == -2) {
        printf("'%s' command timed out.\n", cmd);
    } else if (ret < 0) {
        printf("'%s' command failed.\n", cmd);
    }

    free(cmd);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to read *** pointers, I suggest using structs.

Comment: @Emreİriş yeah, I know but *** make it simpler to iterate over it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think is 8, but to be honest I just used code from another answer.
I wanted to allocate memory for this array of array of strings. So first I allocate memory for the "outer" array with `calloc(*len, sizeof(**scan_result));` and then for each "inner" arrays I allocate with char `**scan_line = calloc(5, items_len);`. So the second array will be an array of 5 **pointers char.

Comment: [Edit] and show show a [mcve]

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok, I will do it.

Comment: This may take a lot of work to untangle.  Your pointers to pointers etc seem pretty mixed up.  The `(char **) &scan` where you cast from `char ****` to `char **` can't possibly be right, and nearly all your `malloc/calloc` calls seem to allocate objects of the wrong type or size.

Comment: In particular the size of the object pointed to by `foo` is always `sizeof(*foo)`, never `sizeof(**foo)`, regardless of what type `foo` is or how many "pointer to pointer" are in its type.

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry, the `(char **) &scan` is a copy-paste error for using old code I will correct those things as don't change the problem. As per the malloc/calloc sizes, I can be wrong, could you point me to the correct sizes?. Thanls

Comment: @xing You are right, it will skip the first position of the scan_result, although sloppy I don't see that assignment beyond allocation can happen. The SEGFAULT occurs at the last `((line = strsep(&scan, "\n")) != NULL )` check of the while block.

Comment: @xing The while loop will run `*len` times as there is `*len` lines, so `i` will be `*len - 1` at the end if I'm correct.

Comment: For example in `scan_result = malloc(wap_scan_size * sizeof(**scan_result))`.  You want space for `wap_scan_size` number of `char **` but you instead allocate space for that many `char *`.  It probably won't cause a problem because they are most likely the same size, but it is worrisome in that it suggests you are not keeping careful track of your pointer types.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the clarification, I will change that as per your suggestion. I don't have too much experience coding in C, so I'm learning as I go. Again thanks for your corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html the issue is that the loop will run one more time than you want it to, causing **scan_result** to overflow.

The relevant parts of the documentation are:

```
   The strsep() function returns a pointer to the token, that is, it
   returns the original value of *stringp.
```

and

```
   If *stringp is NULL, the strsep() function returns NULL and does
   nothing else.  Otherwise, this function finds the first token in
   the string *stringp, that is delimited by one of the bytes in the
   string delim.  This token is terminated by overwriting the
   delimiter with a null byte ('\0'), and *stringp is updated to
   point past the token.  In case no delimiter was found, the token
   is taken to be the entire string *stringp, and *stringp is made
   NULL.
```

In **wap_scan_count_lines** you count the number of lines that are terminated with '\n'.

In the following 2 lines, you allocate the memory to hold the result based on the number of lines terminated with '\n'.

```
int wap_scan_size = wap_scan_count_lines(scan);
scan_result = malloc(wap_scan_size * sizeof(**scan_result));
```

However, the above quoted documentation for **strsep()** implies that in your simplified example the first **wap_scan_size** times strsep is called, at the end of the call the result will not be NULL and **scan** won't be set to NULL during the call.  The next time through the call, **scan** will be set to NULL during the call but the result will not be NULL.  This means that the body of the loop will be executed **wap_scan_size** + 1 times, causing a write past the end of **scan_result**.

There are at least two possible fixes, depending on whether you actually want to process any line at the end of the input that is not terminated by '\n'.

If you do need to process such lines, which seems more robust to me, particularly given that your simplified example ends with such a line, just allocate one extra entry in **scan_result**:

```
scan_result = malloc((wap_scan_size + 1) * sizeof(**scan_result));
```

If you are quite sure that you do not need to process such lines, but this seems incorrect to me, change:

```
while((line = strsep(&scan, "\n")) != NULL ) {
```

to

```
for(line = strsep(&scan, "\n"); scan != NULL; line = strsep(&scan, "\n") ) {
```

Comment: Thanks!!, I really appreciate it. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.